# Hiding the top navigation bar when opening the Navigation Drawer from React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I am building a React Native app in Expo, I want to make it so that when the user opens the navigation drawer it looks like this (without the navigation bar in the top/it being transparent):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZOpT.png)

However, when transforming the app to .apk with eas-cli, and downloading in the same device I tested before, the drawer looks like this when the user opens it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgDSU.png)

These are the screen options I used for my React Native Drawer navigation:

```
   screenOptions={{
      drawerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.secondary,
        width: 250,
      },
      headerTintColor: COLORS.text,
      drawerLabelStyle: {
        color: COLORS.text,
      },
      headerStyle:{ backgroundColor: COLORS.primary },
      headerTitleStyle: { fontFamily: FONT.regular, height: 30, letterSpacing: 2 },
      
    }}
```

It seems to work correctly when running `npm start` and scanning the QR Code from the Expo app in my phone, this issue appears only when downloading the apk from eas-cli.